# How does $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H$ behave with respect to $\bigoplus$?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

How does $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H$ behave with respect to $\bigoplus$? What are the properties of $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H$ with regard to taking direct sums? Any answers or texts to read would be most helpful.

Comment: Are you asking something more nontrivial than the fact that $\text{Ind}_H^G$ distributes over direct sums? Because this is easily found on wolfram alpha, so maybe you are asking something more?

Comment: The functor $\text{ind}_H^G$ is precisely $kG\otimes_H \,?$ and, being a tensor product (or more generally a left adjoint), it preserves all colimits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induced representation is a left adjoint functor, so it preserves colimits, in particular arbitrary direct sums.

Comment: I would change "i.e." to "in particular". Colimits may not always be direct sums.

Comment: You are of course completely right, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The induced representation [distributes over direct sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InducedRepresentation.html).